# Problem with configuration in .NET,problem with read a json file

Tags: c#, json, .net, maui

When I'm trying to add the JSON file via.AddJsonFile(), it throws a:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The expected physical path was '/data/user/0/com.companyname.rakeshproj/files/appsettings.json'.'

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
namespace RakeshProj;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Extensions.JsonRead(@"C:\Users\Matsenko\source\repos\TestJson\TestJson\appsettings.json");
        /////////////////Problem
        IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        //.AddJsonFile("appsettings`.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
        /////////////////Problem
        //Menu menu_settings = config.GetSection("ShellContentNames").Get<Menu>();


        ShellContent[][] ShellContentName= 
        {
        new ShellContent[3]
        {
            ShellContent1_1,ShellContent2_1,ShellContent3_1
        },
        new ShellContent[13]
        {
                 ShellContent1_2,ShellContent2_2,ShellContent3_2,
                 ShellContent4_2,ShellContent5_2,ShellContent6_2,
                 ShellContent7_2,ShellContent8_2,ShellContent9_2,
                 ShellContent10_2,ShellContent11_2,ShellContent12_2,ShellContent13_2    
        }
        };
        string[][] ShellContentTitle =
        {
        new string[3]
        {
            "Test1_1","Test2_1","Test3_1"
        },
        new string[13]
        {
                 "Test1_2","Test2_2","Test3_2",
                 "Test4_2","Test5_2","Test6_2",
                 "Test7_2","Test8_2","Test9_2",
                 "Test10_2","Test11_2","Test12_2","Test13_2"
        }
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < ShellContentName.Length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j < ShellContentName[i].Length; j++)
            {
                ShellContentName[i][j].Title = ShellContentTitle[i][j];
                SemanticScreenReader.Announce(ShellContentName[i][j].Title);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: There is a typo: appsettings`.json

Comment: Yep, I fixed it, but I have the same error McNets.It doesn't depend from the name

Comment: Probably not,check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration.,

Comment: Have a look at Montemagno's blog: https://montemagno.com/dotnet-maui-appsettings-json-configuration/

Comment: @McNets I need an easier way to solve the problem like in Microsoft tutorial that I sent

Comment: Well, Montemagno is a principal lead project manager at Maui.

Comment: @McNets Check please this https://i.stack.imgur.com/EksyH.png

Comment: Have you tried [setting the base path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileconfigurationextensions.setbasepath?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) of your configuration builder to the path of the executing or entrypoint assembly?

Comment: @JoshGust check this https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMQqj.png

Comment: Maybe you know solution

Comment: I'm not as familiar with targeting mobile, but you're setting `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` in your example. Did you try something like `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location`? If the assembly setting the config base bath is the composition root then you could probably just use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`.

Comment: @JoshGust didn't help https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXvnJ.png

Comment: @Matsenko1 sorry, I can see where my suggestion was misunderstood. When you use `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` you're getting the actual assembly file name (ie `.dll`) so try sending that file location to `Path.GetDirectoryName` (ie `.SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location))`).

Comment: @JoshGust https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qDhh.png

Comment: > Have you tried setting the base path of your configuration builder to the path of the *executing* **OR** *entry point* assembly?

Comment: @JoshGust https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjnuD.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if this has something to do with your configuration builder not knowing where that file is being `Copy Always`-ed to. I like to be explicit by setting the base path of my config builder to the location of the executing or entry point assembly.

Try one of these extensions off the builder:

- Using [GetExecutingAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly?view=net-6.0)

  - `.SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))`
- Using [GetEntryAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly?view=net-6.0)

  - `.SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location))`

*The `GetEntryAssembly` version is really only necessary if you're building config in a library or package*

Answer (score -3):

Check properties of the file, they should be like on screenshot:

[image]

Build action: Content

Copy to output directory: Copy if newer

Comment: OP has **Copy always**, which whilst less-than-optimal, should guarantee it working if anything.   Not so with **Copy if newer**

Comment: The same error bruh

Comment: Hey, Copy if newer and copy always do the same thing(kind of).